# Ordinary Generating Function For the Unsigned Stirling numbers of the First Kind

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

On Wikipedia [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), the exponential generating function $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-k}{n\brack k}\frac{z^n}{n!}}=\frac{1}{k!}(\log(1+z))^k$$ is given, where ${n\brack k}$ is the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind. I have done a literature search to see if I could find a similar but **ordinary generating function** for the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind, but I haven't found any.

Could it be that I am not doing a proper search, or no ordinary generating functions for the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind are known? Can someone refer me to some examples they might have seen?

I should mention that I have seen this one: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\brack k}x^k}=x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+n-1),$$ but I am talking about a generating function of a similar kind where the upper summation index is infinity, just as in the case of the exponential generating function I quoted earlier.

Comment: Then you want to write down the OGF of what sequence?

Comment: There are generating functions at https://dlmf.nist.gov/26.8#ii and https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/11/ but I'm not sure if any of them fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I have taken a look at them...but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: In context, I think you will find what you want in Roman's "The Umbral Calculus" (it's cheap) Chapter 4, section 1, at the end of Misc.  You have to do some flimflam to get the functional (1-e^(a*t)) into generating function form; but the formulas are at the beginning of section 1.  If you want context/properties, you have to read the preceding chapters.  If you want, I will write the formulas out.

Comment: I think I remember how to convert the EGF to OGF if needed.

Comment: The OGF $\sum_{n\ge k}{n\brack k}x^n$ does not have a closed form. It is not a proper function, since ${n\brack k}$ grows too quickly, so the radius of convergence is zero. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094705/177399, which I think is a duplicate of your question.

Comment: @rrogers, how to you convert the above EGF to OGF?

Comment: There is an obstacle in the conversion, so I will write a solution in the form of a Generalized Hypergeometric function.  The obstacle is removing the exponential by the definition of the Gamma function; i.e. integrate(f(t)*e^(-t).  Which works fine term by term, but is not helpful for the closed form.   In Hypergeometric form, the removal of the factorial is simple.  Actually, the whole thing is elementary in Hypergeometric form.

Comment: @MikeEarnest  For generating/formal functions, we are not looking for the function value; we are looking for the terms.   As long as the expansion converges term by term to the required values, we don't care if the summation converges.  In other words, we tacitly drop the tail and say it's a finite sequence.  This does hinder things like integration, but that's okay.

Comment: @Poisson -- "removing the exponential" should have been "removing the factorial" :) I was writing the other comment before I noticed that; and the edit period timed out.

Comment: Thank you @rrogers. I am waiting to see your conversion in hypergeometric form.

Answer (score 1):

This my guess at what you want. The “answer” is at the end in Wolfram.
If not please clarify.
As usual: Please read carefully, I am subject to a mathematical dyslexia :)
Constructive comments welcome :)
———————
In order to “ground” the discussion below we start with definitions.
$x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)=\left(x\right)_{n}={\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[\begin{array}{c}
n\\
k
\end{array}\right]x^{k}}$
$s(n,k)=\left(-1\right)^{n-k}\left[\begin{array}{c}
n\\
k
\end{array}\right]$
Notice that $\left(x\right)_{n}$ is the rising product. Which is opposite of Wikipedia; this is a persistent annoyance, not isolated to Wikipedia.
Let:
$G(n,k)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[\begin{array}{c}
n\\
k
\end{array}\right]x^{k}}\cdot\frac{t^{n}}{n!}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}\left(x\right)_{n}\cdot\frac{t^{n}}{n!}}$
Then we can use Wikipedia for
$G\left(n,k\right)=_{1}F_{0}\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
-
\end{array};t\right)=\left(1-t\right)^{-x}$ which rattles on (has an infinite number of terms) but does converge for t<1 (if your interested).
We can eliminate the factorial by
$G\left(n,k\right)=_{2}F_{0}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1,x\\
-
\end{array};t\right)$ which doesn't converge, but we can work term by term; if needed.
But
$H\left(n,k\right)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(-1\right)^{n-k}\cdot s(n,k)\cdot x^{k}}\cdot\frac{t^{n}}{n!}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}\left(-x\right)_{n}\cdot\frac{\left(-t\right)^{n}}{n!}=_{1}F_{0}\left(\begin{array}{c}
-x\\
-
\end{array};-t\right)$
$=\left(1+t\right)^{x}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{x}\frac{x!}{\left(x-n\right)!\cdot n!}t^{n}}$
Does if $x\in N_{+}$
Remark 1. The last term looks strange until we untangle it.
${\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{x}\frac{x!}{\left(x-n\right)!\cdot n!}t^{n}}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{x}\frac{\Gamma\left(x+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(x-n+1\right)}\frac{t^{n}}{n!}}$
and apply the Gamma duality $\Gamma\left(z\right)=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma\left(1-z\right)\cdot sin(\pi\cdot z)}$ which for integer z is $\Gamma\left(z\right)=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{z}\cdot\pi}{\Gamma\left(1-z\right)}$
which yields
${\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{x}\frac{\Gamma\left(-x+n\right)}{\Gamma\left(-x\right)}\cdot\left(-1\right)^{n}\cdot\frac{t^{n}}{n!}=}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{x}\left(-x\right)_{n}\cdot\frac{\left(-t\right)^{n}}{n!}}$
Now when we remove the factorial we have
$_{2}\,F_{0}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1,-x\\
-
\end{array};-t\right)$ does terminate and has representations at
https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/03/01/13/
Line 2 appears to work and is appealing; but that's due to a common programing bug.  Don't "trust" computer algebra programs, find ways to double check them  :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not the same as what I was looking for, but it has given new insight.

Comment: There were several other insights I gathered along the way; to double-check my reasoning.  But I didn't want to add a laundry list of things that nobody was interested in.  If you are ever interested in actually calculating the Sheffer Sequences (Roman), Sheffer/Appell/Associated; let me know.  I invented a mapping from Roman's Umbral Calculus to Matrices, which make some things a lot clearer; and the  programming a lot less tedious and error-prone.

Comment: Okay. Thank you